# How can I override a function in a Node.js module?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using the following module:

https://github.com/AdamPflug/express-brute

The documentation says:

> There are some built-in callbacks that come with BruteExpress that handle some common use cases.

```
ExpressBrute.FailTooManyRequests Terminates the request and responses with a 429 (Too Many Requests) error that has a Retry-After header and a JSON error message.
```

The source code:

https://github.com/AdamPflug/express-brute/blob/36ddf21d0989f337a6b95cd8c945a66e32745597/index.js

defines the following:

```
ExpressBrute.FailTooManyRequests = function (req, res, next, nextValidRequestDate) {
    setRetryAfter(res, nextValidRequestDate);
    res.status(429);
    res.send({error: {text: "Too many requests in this time frame.", nextValidRequestDate: nextValidRequestDate}});
};
```

How do I override that function to make it do what I want to do? In particular, instead of using res.send to send a JSON message, I would like to use res.render to display some HTML.

Comment: You override it just like it gets defined.

Comment: But what about the function 'setRetryAfter' which is internal to index.js and not accessible from where I would be overriding?

Comment: Apparently `ExpressBrute.FailTooManyRequests` is just the default for the `failCallback` option. Set the option to something else and you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit tricky but one could override the methid and keep a reference to the old one, so that it can also run:

```
 { // scope to keep old private
   const old = ExpressBrute.FailTooManyRequests;
   ExpressBrute.FailTooManyRequests = function (req, res, next, nextValidRequestDate) {
      // Call the old one but replace res with a fake response
      old(req, { send() {}, status() {} }, next, nextValidRequestData);
      res.json({ what: "ever!" });
  };
}
```

Comment: I think OP actually wants to override `ExpressBrute.defaults.failCallback`

Comment: @bergi don't know the lib, but sounds as if you are right